# Pumping lemma for regular languages proof

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

I'm trying to prove that if P(L,n) is true then L is regular, where P(L,n) is a property equivalent to the pumping lemma. This is in the context of single letter alphabet. Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Thanks for the advices! I'll keep them in mind in future! I've got a task to prove that if L is a language with single letter alphabet, then if the pumping lemma's conclusion is satisfied L is regular. I understand the proof L is regular -> P(L,n) is true, but i really have not idea what to do if P(L,n) is true. I keep thinking that L mat contain infinitely many different equivalence classes and still P(L,n) is true. I guess that there is something which i dont understand, so im trying to find out what is it and learn it.

Comment: "I keep thinking that L mat contain infinitely many different equivalence classes and still P(L,n) is true. " -- then try to find an example! Doing so will give you insight that you can use to prove the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

We will construct an $NFA$ that decides $L$. Suppose that the single letter is $1$.

Assuming $n$ is the length given by the pumping lemma, every input of size larger than $n$ can be 'pumped' , and remain in $L$.

Let's look at the input: $1^n$. Note that by pumping the input just once, it's size grows by $s$, for $s$ equal or less than $n$(that's by definition).
So every input of length $n + k*s$ , where $k$ is a natural number or $-1$, is in $L$.

We can do the above for every input of size between $n$ and $2n-1$ (why do we need to? and why up to 2n-1?
hint for the first question: think for example on the case where $n = 3$, and $L$ is a language of all the words whose size is divisible by $2$ or $3$).

Then constructing the $NFA$ is quite simple: There is a finite number of words in $L$ of size $<= n$, we will just accept the word if it is of the right size (we can get the sizes by picking $k = -1$ in the previous paragraph).

For words larger than L, we will 'guess' in which form the word is - there are $(2n-1) - n = n-1$ forms available that the language accept (we saw that earlier).

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).

Comment: I think that i got the point. Something i was missing is the part saying that "it's size grows by s, for s equal or less than n" - that was really helpful!

Comment: I realised the idea and i think that i proved it! Thanks again!